# NGXS: How to use Store or set State in meta-reducer

Tags: angular, nativescript, ngxs

I need to dispatch an action from within a meta-reducer or a plugin. I get the following errors when I add this provider to the App Module:

```
   {
       provide: NGXS_PLUGINS,
       useFactory: myfunction,
       deps: [Store],
       multi: true
    }
```

> Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! InternalStateOperations ("[ERROR
>   ->]"): in NgModule AppModule
>
> Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! StateFactory ("[ERROR ->]"): in
>   NgModule AppModule

What is the proper way to do it?

The meta-reducer is:

```
export function extendApplication(store: Store) {
  return function extendApplication(state, action, next) {
  if (state.user.loggedIn){

    if (getActionTypeFromInstance(action) !== LogoutUser.type) {

      here is where I want to set a timer and if no other actions
      occur before the timer expires I want to dispatch a logout action

      return next(state, action);
    }
  }else{
    return next(state, action);
  }}
```

The module has the above provider.

Comment: You would receive the global state in your factory function already. In your code snippet, where the Store is coming from?

Comment: It is in the import statement in the module.ts: 

import { NgxsModule, Store, NGXS_PLUGINS } from '@ngxs/store';

Comment: @Manoj - I updated the code. I can now see that I've got the Store referenced twice -- once in the module provider and then again in the extendApplication function. What would be the proper way to get a reference to the store in the meta-reducer?

Comment: Did you try implementing it as plugin, so you may able to inject store into the constructor?

Comment: I did with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MetaReducers can be implemented via a function or a Service (Class).

If you implement it via a function, you can do:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NGXS_PLUGINS } from '@ngxs/store';
import { getActionTypeFromInstance } from '@ngxs/store';

@NgModule({
  imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([])],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NGXS_PLUGINS,
      useValue: logoutPlugin,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}

export function logoutPlugin(state, action, next) {
  // Use the get action type helper to determine the type
  if (getActionTypeFromInstance(action) === Logout.type) {
    // if we are a logout type, lets erase all the state
    state = {};
  }

  // return the next function with the empty state
  return next(state, action);
}
```

State is mutated just by updating the `state` object passed into the function and passing it back to the returned `next` function.

You can inject the Store in the plugin, using `Injector` and getting the instance, but you can't dispatch an actiom inside the plugin, because you'll create an infinite loop.

If you want to implement it via a Service, you can do:

```
import {
  NGXS_PLUGINS,
  NgxsModule,
  ActionType,
  NgxsNextPluginFn,
  NgxsPlugin
} from "@ngxs/store";
import { Injectable, Inject, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxsModule.forRoot([TestState]),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NGXS_PLUGINS,
      useClass: TestInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}

@Injectable()
export class TestInterceptor implements NgxsPlugin {

  constructor(
    private _injector: Injector
  ){
  }

  public handle(
    state,
    action: ActionType,
    next: NgxsNextPluginFn
  ): NgxsNextPluginFn {
    const matches: (action: ActionType) => boolean = actionMatcher(action);
    const isInitialAction: boolean = matches(InitState) || matches(UpdateState);  

    // you can validate the action executed matches the one you are hooking into
    // and update state accordingly

    // state represents full state obj, if you need to update a specific state, 
    // you need to use the `name` from the @State definition

    state = { test: ["state mutated in plugin"] };

    // get store instance via Injector 
    const store = this._injector.get<Store>(Store);

    return next(state, action);
  }
}
```

I also created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-plugin-example) example if you'd like to check it out

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Actually it doesn't make sense to use middleware when you can use plugin that already has the middleware. This way all we have to do is create action:

```
@Action(RequestLogout)
async requestLogout(context: StateContext<IAuthStateModel>) {
  context.dispatch(new Navigate(['/login']));
  context.dispatch(new StateResetAll());
}
```

**Middleware solution:**

Technically the provided answer is not correct because `{}` doesn't reset app states to their default values.

For future reference for people who will be implementing this I offer following solution:

```
import { ActionType, getActionTypeFromInstance, NgxsNextPluginFn, NgxsPlugin, Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestLogout } from './auth.actions';
import { Navigate } from '@ngxs/router-plugin';
import { StateResetAll } from 'ngxs-reset-plugin';

@Injectable()
export class LogoutMiddleware implements NgxsPlugin {

  constructor(
    private injector: Injector,
  ) {
  }

  public handle(
    state: any,
    action: ActionType,
    next: NgxsNextPluginFn,
  ): NgxsNextPluginFn {
    if (getActionTypeFromInstance(action) === RequestLogout.type) {
      const store = this.injector.get<Store>(Store);
      store.dispatch(new Navigate(['/login']));
      store.dispatch(new StateResetAll());
    }

    return next(state, action);
  }
}
```

Then in your app module, you have to declare the LogoutMiddleware (fun fact meta-reducer is just fancy name for redux middleware) and import NgxsResetPluginModule.

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: NGXS_PLUGINS,
      useClass: LogoutMiddleware,
      multi: true,
    },
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    NgxsResetPluginModule.forRoot(),
    ...
  ],
```